# Problem loading dynamic files with PHP/AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, json, pdf

I have created a fairly secure landing page for our clients to download copies of their contracts.

You hit retrieve.php, the EULA (jQuery Dialog) appears.  After you sign and accept, the jQuery dialog disappears.

An AJAX call is sent to the server to get the hashed filename and a link is generated to view the PDF securely in your browser.

The problem is, now the company wants me to add a JPG version of the contract.  The contract is either 2 or 3 pages, depending on what service they want to use with us.

The problem I am having is how do I generate the correct number of links for the jpg versions?  Everything is done in AJAX, and I would prefer not to return the number of images from AJAX.

The image names are (same hash as pdf)-.jpg

Does anybody have a dynamic way to do this?

I wrote a function that does this in PHP, but since I am running the link generation on the client side, it will not work.

My question is:
I you were me, would you return all 3 or 4 links (pdf + however many jpgs there are) back through JSON?
Would you pass the number of pages back in json and create the links dynamically?
Do you have any better solutions?

Some code:
Here is the AJAX Call that gets sends the info to the server then creates the links:

```
$.ajax({  type: 'POST',
url: 'getContractAJAX.php',
   data: { 
      'pin' : pin.val(),
      'name' : signature.val().toUpperCase(),
      'lead' : '<?php echo $_GET['lead']; ?>'
   }, /* end data */
   cache: false,
   success: function(contractId) {
      if (contractId['success'] == true) {
         contractExpireDate = new Date(contractId['contractExpDate']);
         today = new Date();
         // Log the signature.
         $.post('log.php', {
            signature: $("#electronicSignature").val().toUpperCase(),
        pin: $("#eSpin").val(),
            lead: '<?php echo $_GET['lead']; ?>',
            method: 'SIGNATURE'},
            function(log) {
            if(log['success'] == true) {        

            /* DOWNLOAD IMAGES LINKS */
            $("#downloadLinks").prepend("<a href='#' onclick='log(\""+contractId['contract']+"\", \"DOWNLOAD\");'><img src='img/btnDownloadPdf.png' alt='Downdload PDF' /><br />Download Contract in Adobe &copy; PDF</a>");

         } else {
            alert("There was a problem! Please contact customer support.");
            showDisclosure();
         } /* end else */
                                            }); /* end function(log) */
                                            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("close");
```

getContractAJAX.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['pin']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['lead'])){
    $pin = $_POST['pin'];
    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $email = $converter->decode($_POST['lead']);



    /*
     * 
     * 
     * PDO
     * 
     * 
     */
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT contract, contractExpireDate 
                            FROM users 
                            WHERE   emailAddress=:email AND 
                                    pin=:pin AND 
                                    concat(firstName, ' ', lastName) LIKE :name AND
                                    contractExpireDate > NOW()
                            LIMIT 1");

    if ($stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR) &&
        $stmt->bindParam(':pin', $pin, PDO::PARAM_INT) &&
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR)) {
        $stmt->execute();

        $found = 0;
        foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $el) {
            $found++;
            $contract = $el['contract'];
            $contractExpDate = $el['contractExpireDate'];
        }
        $stmt = null;
    }               

    if ($found > 0) {
        $success = true;
    } else {
        $success = false;
        $error = "NO MATCHES FOUND >>> $email >>> $pin >>> $name";
    }


}else{
    $success = false;
    $error = "NOT ALL PASSED";
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
$json = array("contract" => $contract,
              "contractExpDate" => $contractExpDate,
              "success" => $success,
              "messege" => $error);
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: some code please? we are not geniuses at figuring out ur code lol

Comment: The image name should be (same hash as pdf)-(page#).jpg... I put that in greater and less than signs and got filtered....

Comment: sure...its a huge script so I'll try to highlight the parts in question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not return a single compressed file (tar, zip, etc.) of all of the images? That would give you a single download and makes the download faster/smaller.

Comment: Its not exactly user friendly.  The boss is pretty specific on what he wants.  He wants a link to the PDF, or a link to the 2 or 3 pages in JPG version.

Comment: @Mark I don't see how it's not user friendly -- I'd say anything saving clicks would be. But considering the constraints and looking at your code, I would just add an 'images' key or something to your JSON and output a list of thumbnails linking to their download.